# Resampling tick data from websocket into bars and checking for increases in size of the resample object

Tags: pandas, python-asyncio, algorithmic-trading

I am writing a base class which pulls tick data from a zero MQ server, and resamples that data into a dataframe.  I want to send the latest resampled bar to another module of the trading engine once and only once that new row appears within the resample object. I.e if I resample every 10 seconds, a new row [the last row] would appear within the resample object every 10 seconds, which would then be fired out. I figure that I need to first detect when the size of the resample object increases by one, and then I need to just extract the last row of the resample object and fire it out. How do I write this in the context of the async while loop that exists around the code please? Its straightforward to extract the length of the dataframe by placing a print statement where my capital letter pseudo code is in the example below but how do I compare that current number with 'prior states'? Code below:

```
class LiveBarDataHandler(DataHandler):

def __init__(self, events, symbol_list):

    self.events = events
    self.symbol_list = symbol_list
    self.symbol_data = {}
    self.latest_symbol_data = {}
    self.continue_backtest = True
    self.bar_index = 0
    self._create_connection_to_server()
async def handle_bar_data(self):
    ticks = pd.DataFrame()
    while True:
        msg = self.socket.recv_string()
        data = json.loads(msg)
        df = pd.DataFrame({'SYMBOL': data['SYMBOL'],
                           'PRICE': data['PRICE']},
                          index=[pd.Timestamp(data['TIME'])])
        ticks = pd.concat((ticks, df))
        for symbol in set(ticks['SYMBOL']):

            self.symbol_data[symbol] = (ticks[ticks['SYMBOL'] == symbol]['PRICE']
                                .resample('10S').ohlc()
                                .ffill()
                                .iloc[:-1]
                                )
            PSEUDO CODE: CHECK RESAMPLED DF [self.symbol_data[symbol]] FOR NEW ROW AND SEND SIGNAL / PRINT STATEMENT
```